# Phabricator: Unable to create diffs

Tags: phabricator

I tried to create diff in phabricator from the GUI and it is giving the following exception:

> Diff Parse Exception: Expected a hunk header, like 'Index:
>   /path/to/file.ext' (svn), 'Property changes on: /path/to/file.ext'
>   (svn properties), 'commit 59bcc3ad6775562f845953cf01624225' (git
>   show), 'diff --git' (git diff), '--- filename' (unified diff), or
>   'diff -r' (hg diff or patch).

I am unable to ascertain what is causing this exception.

Comment: Can you put more details? Maybe a sample of what you are inputting? I'm guessing you aren't inputting a diff in the format they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I see same issue with phabricator and Hg for patches creates with  hg export command. But for hg diff

non working:
hg export -r 118:120 > patch.diff

Working solution is :
 hg diff -r 118:120 >patch.diff

Answer (score 0):

One issue they were discussing at [Phacility](https://secure.phabricator.com/T7068) is about your language setting. Possibly you have a different language in your SVN (?) than English. The preferred way is to use arcanist to create the diffs, as it really handles the different languages of your SCM.